# Header with tabs and listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-xml

I will first explain what i want to do. Here is a image preview i made to explain:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx1sa.png

At the top I have a layout header with image and text "Hello, world!". Below I want to use [this Github library](https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip). Under that, I need a ListView where I will load data into.

When you scroll vertically, it should work as normal, everything, including the ListView and top layout/tabs, on the screen scrolls normally.

When I slide horizontal, I want the top layout/tabs to not change, only the ListView data should change.

I am not asking for code, I am asking how I should do all this? What layouts should I use, how do I do the scrolling?

Does anyone know another app that does this what i need?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to implement a `HorizontalScrollView` or how to switch `ListView`s when you do? Or something else??

Comment: I am asking what layout types i should use, how to make whole screen scrollable vertically (and not just Listview) and how to keep the top layout/tabs fixed when swiping horizontal with ViewPager.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but I will attempt to answer some parts of it.

If you want the top to "anchor" then you need to use a relative layout for the whole screen and put those images in another layout. The `ListView` then sits below that.

To add multiple `ListView`s you could use a `HorzontalScrollView` with `ListView` elements. This is tricky because of the dual scrolling effect also possible memory issues, depending on how you load them. This is essentially a "two way scroll" or you may try a horizontal `ListView` with it's elements being `ListView`s. It really depends on how customized you want the display, how many items are in each, how much time/money you have and how customized you want the view/controller to be.

See this: http://profi.co/android-horizontal-list-view-library-with-item-scroll/

And a "snapping" effect example: http://www.velir.com/blog/index.php/2010/11/17/android-snapping-horizontal-scroll/